# How do you stop a shortcode from firing in the editor?

Tags: shortcode

I created a custom short code that includes creating an on page table along with a few other things. But the short code is loading in the editor as well, and it is causing errors and preventing me from uploading the page. Is there a way to stop the short code from firing in the editor, or did I improperly code something?

[image]

Comment: Does your shortcode code echo its output or return it? It should return it.

Comment: It does echo it, but only because there is so much content. I build the entire table based on the mysqli results. That could very well be the cause though.

Comment: Shortcodes _must_ return their output, regardless of how much content there is. It's not a matter of convenience, it's how they work. For large amounts of content/HTML use `ob_start()` to capture output, and `return ob_get_clean()` to return the captured output.

Comment: I was worried about needing to break in and out of HTML a hundred times and trying to add it to a variable to return; but you dont need to with output buffering. Thanks @JacobPeattie, want to make an answer I can mark it?

Answer (score 0):

First follow what the codex says [Shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output). Basically you just wrap your html in ob_start(); this will return the html as a string so you can echo it.
1st way :

```
function my_shortcode() {
ob_start();
?> <HTML> <here> ... <?php
return ob_get_clean();
```

}

2nd way

```
function my_shortcode() {
$output = '';
$output.= '<html>content</html>';
return $output;
```

}